# python async with timer and endless loop

Tags: python, loops, timer, python-asyncio

I have found two parts of code here for my planned project.
The first with two timers ...

```
class Timer:
    def __init__(self, interval, first_immediately, timer_name, context, callback):
        self._interval = interval
        self._first_immediately = first_immediately
        self._name = timer_name
        self._context = context
        self._callback = callback
        self._is_first_call = True
        self._ok = True
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())
        print(timer_name + " init done")

    async def _job(self):
        try:
            while self._ok:
                if not self._is_first_call or not self._first_immediately:
                    await asyncio.sleep(self._interval)
                await self._callback(self._name, self._context, self)
                self._is_first_call = False
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def cancel(self):
        self._ok = False
        self._task.cancel()

async def timer1(timer_name, context, timer):
    context['count'] += 1
    print('callback: ' + timer_name + ", count: " + str(context['count']))


async def timer2(timer_name, context, timer):
    context['count'] += 1
    print('callback: ' + timer_name + ", count: " + str(context['count']))

t1 = Timer(interval=1, first_immediately=True, timer_name="Timer Channel", context={'count': 0}, callback=timer1)
t2 = Timer(interval=3, first_immediately=False, timer_name="Timer Scroll", context={'count': 0}, callback=timer2)

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    t1.cancel()
    t2.cancel()
    print("clean up done")
```

and the second with an endless loop for checking events ...

```
while True:
for key, mask in selector.select():
    device = key.fileobj

    for event in device.read():
        ecode = event.code
        if event.type == evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY:
            match event.code:
                case 114:
                    print("Vol down")
                case 115:
                    print("Vol up")
```

Everything works as it should, but I don't know how to set it up so that everything runs independently without interfering with the other processes.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There's several things that need to change.

First of all, you never schedule anything.
Create an entry point, something like `async def main()` where you start your logic (instantiating the timers and so forth), then do `asyncio.run(main())`. This will create an eventloop en schedule the your `main` function.

```
import asyncio

# entrypoint for everything that needs to run async
async def main():

    try:
        t1 = Timer(interval=1, first_immediately=True, timer_name="Timer Channel", context={'count': 0}, callback=timer1)
        t2 = Timer(interval=3, first_immediately=False, timer_name="Timer Scroll", context={'count': 0}, callback=timer2)

        # some sync/async logic or loop...
        while True:
            # either do some async work or use asyncio.sleep(0) 
            # so other tasks get a chance to run.
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        t1.cancel()
        t2.cancel()
        print("clean up done")

# Best practice to check for '__main__'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start the eventloop en schedule your "entrypoint"
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Next up, you have async functions that aren't async. `timer1` and `timer2` don't await anything so there's no need for them to be asynchronous.

```
# note: I've removed the async keyword
def timer1(timer_name, context, timer):
    context['count'] += 1
    print('callback: ' + timer_name + ", count: " + str(context['count']))
```

And since these functions aren't async we don't need to await them.

*Sidenote*: While `asyncio.ensure_future` isn't wrong, the docs encourage the use of `asyncio.create_task` instead. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future).

```
async def _job(self):
    try:
        while self._ok:
            if not self._is_first_call or not self._first_immediately:
                await asyncio.sleep(self._interval)

            # await self._callback(self._name, self._context, self)
            self._callback(self._name, self._context, self)

            self._is_first_call = False
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

```
def __init__(self, interval, first_immediately, timer_name, context, callback):
    self._interval = interval
    self._first_immediately = first_immediately
    self._name = timer_name
    self._context = context
    self._callback = callback
    self._is_first_call = True
    self._ok = True
    # self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._job())
    print(timer_name + " init done")
```

If you have any other questions, or if I misunderstood anything then feel free to let me know!

Ps. https://superfastpython.com/python-asyncio/ is a great source of information regarding anything async.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this gives me the output:  
timer1 init done  
timer2 init done  
callback: timer1, count: 1

Comment: Are you running a loop within the main? Otherwise the function will just exit after starting everything. Also the loop should be async so the eventloop gets a chance to run other tasks, i'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry for the mess of posts. I had difficulties with creating and sending the posts

Answer (score 0):

I had used my keyboard event loop from above as the loop. That was my aim, to integrate it. But even with your addition above, it doesn't work.

```
import asyncio

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, interval, first_immediately, timer_name, context, callback):
    self._interval = interval
    self._first_immediately = first_immediately
    self._name = timer_name
    self._context = context
    self._callback = callback
    self._is_first_call = True
    self._ok = True
    # self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._job())
    print(timer_name + " init done")

    async def _job(self):
        try:
            while self._ok:
                if not self._is_first_call or not self._first_immediately:
                await asyncio.sleep(self._interval)
                self._callback(self._name, self._context, self)
                self._is_first_call = False
        except Exception as ex:
           print(ex)
    def cancel(self):
        self._ok = False
        self._task.cancel()

def timer1(timer_name, context, timer):
    context['count'] += 1
    print('callback: ' + timer_name + ", count: " + str(context['count']))

def timer2(timer_name, context, timer):
    context['count'] += 1
    print('callback: ' + timer_name + ", count: " + str(context['count']))

async def main():
    try:
        t1 = Timer(interval=1, first_immediately=True, timer_name="timer1", context={'count': 0}, callback=timer1)
        t2 = Timer(interval=3, first_immediately=False, timer_name="timer2", context={'count': 0}, callback=timer2)
    # some sync/async logic or loop...
        while True:
            asyncio.sleep(0) 

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        t1.cancel()
        t2.cancel()
        print("clean up done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

... then it does not work.
The output is:

```
timer1 init done    
timer2 init done
/home/pi/zradio/z10b.py:41: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
asyncio.sleep(0)  
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: `asyncio.sleep(0)` is a coroutine you should await it. `await asyncio.sleep(0)`